# sed command to substitute any content after equals on line 3 with a string

Tags: sed, substitution

I am trying to substitute this line

```
<data_item name="any_text">
```

which is on line 3 with

```
<data_item name="my_text">
```

So I tried something like `sed '3s/=*/=my_text/' input_file > output_file`

But this is printing my text at the beginning of the line. Tried braces around `(=*)` and `(=my_text)` but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed '3s/any_text/my_text/' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '<data_item name="any_text">' | sed '1s/any_text/my_text/'
<data_item name="my_text">
```

Your code:

```
sed '3s/=*/=my_text/'
```

Your code will replace 0 or more equals on the third line with `=my_text`.

Answer (score 0):

`sed '3s/=".*"/="mytext"/'`

should work. You need the `.` because it matches any character and the `*` says you want 0 or more of the preceding symbol `.`. In regex terms the `*` doesn't mean match anything. It is a quantifier which means it specifies and amount and is generally used to specify the number of the preceding terms you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '3 c\
<data_item name="my_text">' YourFile
```

Assuming that the content of `my_text` does not contain unescape `\` `&` and `'`

avoid `<` and `>` on same file in samle instruction, could have unexpected result. Use a temporary file on `-i` on GNU sed